# Flexicious Highlighted Cell

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, highlight, flexicious

I'm wondering about highlighted cells in Flexicious Ultimate DataGrid. Not highlighted rows, but highlighted cells. I think maybe they are called active cells?

But my question is how can I remove all highligting of cells from the Grid? I don't want this functionality to occur. I can't find a way to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
enableActiveCellHighlight=false
```